# Android Hardware Echo Cancellation Detection

Tags: android, hardware

Some of the new Android phones are having Hardware Echo Cancellation capability.

Is there a way to detect if a device has hardware echo cancellation capability? We have software echo cancellation in one of our app and like to disable it at run-time if hardware echo cancellation is present.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried that? it's not reliable in saying if it's HEC or SEC and already been discussed.

Comment: discussed where? why didn't you mention it in your question?

Comment: @Yusuf If it's reliable or not that depends on the Android equipment manufacturer, because some of them doesn't follows the Android standards as should.

Comment: AudioFX only indicated if AEC is available, even if it's implemented in software.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use the "isAvailable()" method of the AccousticEchoCanceler class. [This is the docs description](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/AcousticEchoCanceler.html#isAvailable()).

Comment: it only indicated if AEC is available, even if it's implemented in software.

Comment: As far as I know, if it's implemented by hardware then you shouldn't be capable to detect it if it isn't exposed in the SDK.

Comment: You could I think get the chipset information and then comparing it to a database of known hardware echo cancellation capable devices.

Comment: Also depending how is implemented the audio path internally some devices could cancel their own hardware cancellation capabilities if you put yours using this class. If this isn't the case then you're out of luck.